# Python Scrapy override content type to be multipart/form-data on post Request

Tags: python, scrapy, multipart

Trying to use scrapy to scrape a website which encodes its post requests as "multipart/form-data" for some reason.

Is there a way to override scrapy's default behavior of posting using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

It looks like the site is not responding to the spider because it wants its requests posted using "multipart/form-data".

Have tried multipart encoding the form variables but have seen using wireshark that scrapy still sets the header incorrectly irrespective of this encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [scrapy.http.FormRequest](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) instead of scrapy.Request, passing the parameters in the formdata argument.

Sample code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ...
    def start_requests(self):
        yield FormRequest(some_post_url,
                          formdata=dict(param1='value1', param2='value2'))
```

#### Read more:

- [Request usage examples](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-usage-examples)
- [FormRequest objects](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)

Comment: This is what we are using, it encodes our form data using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", adding in percent symbols when we want "multipart/form-data" which doesn't interfere with our data (carriage returns and newline byte-codes). Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: @Barfe have you tried using: ``yield FormRequest(..., headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})`` ?

Comment: Yes we have! Thank you very much for your help, accepted your answer!

Comment: @elias can you please help me how to write the request for this url https://www.gumtree.com/reply/1148431421  when we click send button? I tried your approach but that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent way more time on this than I would have liked to, so here is my rundown of the situation in `scrapy`.

## Background

`multipart/form-data` content types have a particular kind of encoding that you need to follow. You can see an example of this inspecting the `Network` tab in `Developer tools` of any major browser, while sending this type of request. Here is an example of a `multipart/form-data` request body/payload

```
-----------------------------9128252932315252835063017
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

tibor.udvari
-----------------------------9128252932315252835063017
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="passwd"

secret
-----------------------------9128252932315252835063017
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_mode"

edit
-----------------------------9128252932315252835063017--
```

You will also have to set the appropriate `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` in the headers.

## Implementation

At the time of writing, `Scrapy 1.4` does not have a facilitated way to send `multipart/form-data` requests. You will have to construct a post request yourself.

First, you need to construct the request out of your data, I am using  `MultipartEncoder` class out of `requests-toolbelt` to do so.

```
formdata = {'username': 'example', 'password': 'example'}
me = MultipartEncoder(fields=formdata)
me_boundary = me.boundary[2:]  #need this in headers
me_length = me.len             #need this in headers
me_body = me.to_string()       #contains the request body
```

Next step is to create the request with valid headers

```
headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + me_boundary,
        'Content-Length': me_length
}
r = scrapy.Request(url='https://example.com', method='POST', body=me_body, headers=headers)
```

Sending this request should yield a valid response, if it is somehow malformed, you should get a server reponse saying something like "upload error".

Assuming that you are using `scrapy shell` you may now send out the request

```
fetch(r)
```

## Limitations

I have only tested this with text inputs, handling files might require more steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this MultipartRequest:

Code:

```
from scrapy import Request
from StringIO import StringIO

import mimetypes
import random


class MultipartRequest(Request):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formdata = kwargs.pop('formdata', None)
        files = kwargs.pop('files', None)

        kwargs['method'] = 'POST'

        super(MultipartRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._boundary = '-----------------------------{0}'.format(random.random() * 1e10)

        if formdata or files:
            buffer = StringIO()

            if formdata:
                self._write_formdata(formdata, buffer)

            if files:
                self._write_files(files, buffer)

            self.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary={0}'.format(self._boundary)
            self._set_body(buffer.getvalue())


    def _write_formdata(self, formdata, buffer):
        for key, value in formdata.iteritems():
            buffer.write('--{0}\r\n'.format(self._boundary))
            buffer.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{0}"\r\n'.format(key))
            buffer.write('\r\n')
            buffer.write('{0}\r\n'.format(str(value).encode('utf-8')))

    def _write_files(self, files, buffer):
        for key, filedesc, fd in files:
            buffer.write('--{0}\r\n'.format(self._boundary))
            buffer.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{0}"; filename="{1}"\r\n'.format(key, filedesc))
            buffer.write('Content-Type: {0}\r\n'.format(self.get_content_type(filedesc)))
            buffer.write('\r\n')

            if isinstance(fd, basestring):
                buffer.write(fd)
            else:
                buffer.write(fd.getvalue())

            buffer.write('\r\n')
            buffer.write('--{0}--\r\n'.format(self._boundary))
            buffer.write('\r\n')


    def get_content_type(self, filepath):
        return mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```