# scrapy can not login

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a forum but can not log in. I checked by chrome dev tools and found that this site does not have any token etc. However, formrequest does not work. Could someone possibly find what am I doing wrong?

```
class WbcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  '''
  yield_dict: mandantory keys
    db_handler
    meta_dict
    error
    result
  '''
  name = 'wbc'

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.start_ric_url_dict = {
        'wbc': 'https://hotcopper.com.au/asx/wbc/discussion/?post_view=0'
    }

    # flags' dict for determing whether keep scraping
    self.comment_cont_dict = dict()
    self.post_cont_dict = dict()
    self.max_old_num = 5
    self.stop_date_flag = dp.parse('2018-12-31')
    self.scrapy_meta_keys = [
        'depth', 'download_timeout', 'download_slot', 'download_latency', '_id'
    ]


  def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://hotcopper.com.au/login/', callback=self.login)

  def login(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={
            'login': '***',
            'password': '***',
            'remember': '1',
            'cookie_check': '1',
            'tos': '1',
            'redirect': 'https://hotcopper.com.au/',
            '_xfToken': '',
            '_xfResponseType': 'json',
            '_xfRequestUri': '/login/'
        },
        callback=self.after_login, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: what response do you get?

Comment: You should probably change your credentials on that site (and every site where you use the same email/password), even if they where  exposed only for some seconds; if that account was any worth to you.

Comment: when I check this login form in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox then I see it is not normal POST but it sends data as "multipart/form-data". See: [Python Scrapy override content type to be multipart/form-data on post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947131/python-scrapy-override-content-type-to-be-multipart-form-data-on-post-request)

Comment: @furas Tks for your reference. I followed it but get another error. Would you pls take a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480780/scrapy-login-through-multipart-form-data-get-400-error Many thanks!